# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'xyz'

Tags: java, php, mysql, vb.net, jdbc

I've created this database in mysql by **phpmyadmin**. It works absolutely fine when I access it from my **vb.net** application. But when I'm trying to connect it from my java application it's showing exception:

```
"com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
                                        Unknown database 'gm'".
```

Even I cannot connect to any database that has been created by me from Java application. But the same databases works fine for php or VB.net applications. Java application can connect to "`information_schema`" database though using the same code.

Please help. Thanks in advance.
[Databases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TRiV.jpg)[privileges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv4xi.jpg)

Comment: It'll easier to help if you share your code

Comment: Please tell me how can I add the code here. I'm new here. Can't find a place to edit the question or add code.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that database xyz exists, I have a feeling your connection string is attempting to hit the wrong database.

Below is a correct example of a connection string for jdbc.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname
```

You should also check that the user you're attempting to connect to the database with also has permissions for that database?

Comment: Hi DominicEU, I've spelled the dbname correctly. It cannot connect any of the databases that is created by me. But it can connect to database "information_schema" which was a pre-defined database.

Comment: Could you provide the output from show databases; (or a screenshot from phpmyadmin) ? Are you sure the user you're trying to connect with has the appropriate permissions.

Comment: Please tell me how can I add screenshot in the question. I'm new in it. Can't find it.

Comment: Click edit on the main post, and then click the image icon.

Comment: Hi DominicEU, I've added screenshot of databases and the privileges.

Comment: There's a trailing ' on your connection string "gm'". Remove it.

Comment: My Connection String is - Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/gm","root","")

Comment: 3307 is definitely the right port? You should be able to check from phpmyadmin. 3306 is default.